# How to do numerical line integral?

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a 2D numeric (interpolating) function **J** that represents the current density of a square plate. I'd like to integrate **J** along one edge to find the total current coming out of that side.

I'm currently using

```
NIntegrate[J, {x, 9, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

The plate spans from 0 to 10 in the y and x directions. Obviously, I'd like to know the current coming out of the end at $x=10$. Is there a way I can do a line integral along that edge to get a more accurate number instead of doing an area integral of a thin strip?

Comment: You can parametrize the line segment representing the edge of interest, and then make the necessary substitutions, so that your integrand looks like `J[x[t], y[t]] Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2]`.

Comment: See the sections "Lengths, Areas, and Volumes" and "Line, Volume, and Surface integrals" in [NIntegrate's function page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) for concrete examples related to J.M.'s advice.

Comment: How about `NIntegrate[J /. x -> 10, {y, 0, 10}]`?

Comment: Coolwater - thanks, worked like a charm!